Weird lines on materials
i am learning Blender for a while now and yesterday in my new project the same issue appeared as in a previous one.
As you can see there are those weird straight lines on the silver material. They are visible in the viewport and they also show up in the render.
I thought it's because of the normals so i fixed them but the lines did not disappear.
Maybe i did something wrong with the UV editing. Can someone help me please?
Link to file with packed image:


hello please pack your images and share your file

An image showing your object in Edit mode in Solid view would be helpful too!

@moonboots how can i share the file here?

You can use a platform like workupload and share the link

@moonboots thank you. here is the file and the image.
https://workupload.com/archive/FK4ZfXjgUE
i followed this tutorial on yt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9ddNZLHh1w&t=314s
But i used a png from google instead of his material.
Think this is also part of the issue.

@Anna-Lena If your Blend file with packed images (File > External Data > Pack Images in Blender) is smaller than 30Meg you can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

@JohnEason the link is in the description now. Is it right like this?

That's fine, but next time it would be helpful to use blend-exchange.com as the file will then remain available for future users reading this question. You would have to pack the images first though as blend-exchange only accepts Blend files.

@JohnEason i see. i changed it again. So now this is like you mean?

@Ana See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251624/binding-materials-to-mesh/251627#251627

@Anna-Lena Yes. That's fine thanks. Anyhow you now have an answer from moonboots

It comes from these vertical lines that you can see if you push the contrast of your image, repaint these parts and these artefacts will disappear:


oh wow okay. haha bit embarrassing i didn't notice that :D thank you so much for your time and help!
